# Вычисление суммы положительных элементов матрицы, находящихся над главной диагональю

Tags: матрицы

Проверьте пожалуйста программу:
В[10][10]   Вычислите сумму положительных элементов матрицы, находящихся над главной диагональю. B - вещественные числа

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   float i,j,B[10][10],s;
   s=0;
   printf("vv elementy matritsy B:\n");
   for (i=0;i<10;i++)
       for (j=0;j<10;j++)
           scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);
   printf("martitsa B:\n");
   for (i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     for (j=0;j<10;j++)
       printf("%d\t",B[i][j]);
     printf("\n");}
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       for (j=0;j<10;j++)
          if(i<j)
              s=s+B[i][j];
     }  
     printf("s=%d",s);
     getch();
}
```

Comment: Для начала: а где проверка на положительность элемента матрицы?

Answer (score 1):

Проверил, нормально. Только printf("s=%d",s); надо заменить, например, на

```
printf("s=%g",double(s));
```

Comment: @Михаил М, плохо проверили.В 2-х последних вложенных циклах, по крайней мере, одна трагическая ошибка и одна неточность

Comment: скажите ,пожалуйста, в чем ошибка

Comment: Увы мне! Действительно, на положительные нет проверки